# Highcharts reflow

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

Hi guys I inherited some code handling highcharts and I'm struggling with it little bit.

I'm not able to post code, but in short, I have a chart with two series (one - regular line, and second - just points). And I have noticed that my series with points is somehow **clipped** or **cropped** so only half of points are displayed when I try to reflow chart with:

```
$scope.$broadcast('highchartsng.reflow');
```

What I have tried so far:

> plotOptions > series > dataGrouping > enable set to false
>
> series > clip: false
>
> series > animation: false

But problem persist ... any ideas?

Comment: Please post some code / fiddle or Gist relating to this issue which will really be helpful.

Comment: *I'm not able to post code* I can understand about not posting sensitive data but the code with some dummy data shoudn't be a problem.